# How to print webpage footer starting on the second printed page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I am trying to print the footer of a page using HTML. However, I need the footer to start only on the second page. The number of pages that will be generated varied from document to document. So far, it either shows up in every page or towards the end of the page.

**JavaScript:**

```
if (lineNo > 35) {
    content += "<div id='print-footer' width=100%>";
    content += "<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=100% border=0>";
    content += "<tr><td style='font-family: Times New Roman; font-size:12px;'>Ref No.: " + tranId + "</td></tr>";
    content += "</table>";
    content += "</div>";
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">

  div#print-footer {
    position: fixed;
    right: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: white
  }

</style>
```

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. Ideally, **in addition** to the code in the question body itself, please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/jquery/1.7.1/) example of your problem. It will help us help you.

Comment: Footer still appears on all pages. The document I am generating now has 4 pages in total

Comment: It appears on all pages because you're calling `position: fixed` on it.

Comment: I notice that your content += seems to be improperly coded. For example, you need to use `style="width:100%"` inside of the `div`.

Comment: arttronics, that appears to be a typo when copying it here

Comment: Truth, I changed the position to absolute , inherit. However, they both only show footer on first page. Other pages are missing.

Comment: @user1033038, please paste your JavaScript at [**jsFiddle.net**](http://jsfiddle.net) or [**pastebin.com**](http://pastebin.com/) so we can see the actual markup you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the footer on the first page

```
div#print-footer:nth-of-type(1) {
     ... css for hiding the footer
}
```

By the way, you should not use `id='print-footer'` because it looks like it is present more than one time. Use `class='print-footer'` and replace the `#` with a dot `.` in your css

**EDIT:** Add another variable to keep track of the pages. You can use it as pagenumbering too if you want.

Create a global for printing

```
pageNo = 1;
```

And omit the footer for first page

```
if (lineNo > 35) {
  if (pageNo > 1) {
    content += "<div id='print-footer' width=100%>";
    content += "<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=100% border=0>";
    content += "<tr><td style='font-family: Times New Roman; font-size:12px;'>Ref No.: " + tranId + "</td></tr>";
    content += "</table>";
    content += "</div>";
  }
  pageNo++;
}
```

**EDIT2:**

For the first solution a simple sample in [**this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WxLYu/) to see how the first `print-footer` is hidden

Comment: What determines the first printed page? I suggested to use `height:0%` via an `else` statement to go with the questions `if` statement but that did not work.

Comment: Updated answer with another possible solution

Comment: can you elaborate more on the first solution? it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Your solution only hides the first div. However the issue here is everytime the footer is printed, it ended up at the bottom of the last page. The text becomes darker when the same text is printed over again and again.

Comment: Now I am confused. You stat that the footer appears on all pages but you need to have it skipped on the first page. Now you come with a comment that the footer is printed on the last page only.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. If i set position:fixed in the CSS, it appears on all pages, on the other hand if i set position:absolute it appears only on the last page.

Comment: Then what's the problem using `position: fixed` and `:nth-of-type(1)` Its exactly what you asked for

Comment: position:fixed makes it appear on all pages. After setting that, ntg-of-type(1) have no effect on the footer. Footer still appears on all pages. I guess this is quite impossible to be done since css does not recognize when to break a page during printing.

Comment: did you try to add `!important` to the `nth-of-type` css and then in particular the line that hides the footer? so you get something like this `#print-footer:nth-of-type(1) { visibility: hidden !important; }`

Comment: Look here how to add page breaks: http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks for printing

Comment: still doesn't work. As mentioned, there will be a table populated dynamically, therefore, page breaks should also be generated dynamically.